# How to re color image in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, colors, color-blending

I have images of human face features like eyes,nose, mouth and i want  to re color them in different skin tones. I tried `colorBlendMode` but that is not giving expected output. So, i wanna know that is there any library or method that can help me to change the color ?

[image]

This is how image looks like i want to blend them into single color so that it should look like an actual image